# variable wont decrement by one inside array brackets. What am I doing wrong

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

Can anyone help me fix this? Coming back to coding after years. I did do quite a few searches online before coming here. I noticed that `i` needed to be decremented so I did this the way I normally do it in almost every other language. Why is python giving me so much trouble (syntax error) decrementing `i` in `enemies[]` by one?

```
        for i in range(len(enemies)):
        enemy_x, enemy_y, enemy_speed = enemies[i -= 1]
```

Comment: Simply iterate over each `enemy`: `for enemy in enemies: do_stuff()`.

Answer (score 0):

`i -= 1` is an assignment statement (which results in re-assigning `i`), not an expression with a value.  The `[]` operator expects a value that can be used as an index.

Since `for i in range...` is giving you increasing values of `i`, you don't want to re-assign `i` inside the loop anyway; just subtract from it and use the resulting value:

```
for i in range(len(enemies)):
    enemy_x, enemy_y, enemy_speed = enemies[i - 1]
```

Note that the first iteration of your loop will give you the *last* enemy (`enemies[-1]`).  If that's not what you intended, you might find it easier to just iterate over `enemies` directly:

```
for enemy_x, enemy_y, enemy_speed in enemies:
    # do stuff with those three variables
```